# AHK Break Loop on Release and continue on keypress

Tags: loops, release, autohotkey, break, continue

im looking for advice to tweak the attached script.

When xbutton2 is pressed down the loop is executed and repeated fine, but i struggle with stopping the loop like i want to.

Ideally i want to stop the loop as fast as possible when xbutton2 is released.

Further i would like the loop to jump to the start if a certain key (or a specified range of keys) is pressed while still holding xbutton2.

xbutton2 down = 1-(400ms)-2-(400ms)-3-(400ms)-4-(750ms)-5-(500ms) - etc

xbutton2 down and released after send 3 = 1-(400ms)-2-(400ms)-3 -**xbutton2 released**

xbutton2 down and x is pressed after send 3= 1-(400ms)-2-(400ms)-3 **-X-** 1-(400ms)-2-(400ms) etc

```
SetNumlockState, Alwayson
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 3


$*XButton2::

loop
    {
if not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")
        break
Send {Blind} {1}
sleep 400
 if (not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")or GetKeyState("x", "P"))
        continue
Send {Blind} {2}
sleep 400    
 if (not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")or GetKeyState("x", "P"))
        continue
Send {Blind} {3} 
sleep 400 
 if (not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")or GetKeyState("x", "P"))
        continue
Send {Blind} {4}
    sleep 750
 if (not GetKeyState("XButton2", "P")or GetKeyState("x", "P"))
        continue
Send {Blind} {5}
sleep 500
}

return
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try starting from this example from the [AHK forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/64576-the-definitive-autofire-thread/):

```
list=a,b,c,{enter},string{click}    ; the list of keys and combos. comma separated. 
stringsplit, list, list,`,
Counter = 0

$F8::
    While GetKeyState("F8","P"){
        Counter := (Counter=list0) ? (1) : (Counter+1)
        Send % list%counter%
        Sleep 50
    }
return
```

You can reset the counter to "0" with an additional hotkey. I think that the following might work for you:

```
list={Blind}{1},{Blind}{2},{Blind}{3},{Blind}{4},{Blind}{5}
stringsplit, list, list,`,
Counter = 0

$*XButton2::
    While GetKeyState("XButton2","P"){
        Counter := (Counter=list0) ? (1) : (Counter+1)
        Send % list%counter%
        Sleep 400
    }
return

x::Counter = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, and i like the idea. what would be the best way to deal with variable sleep timers, since the timing between the send commands varies.

Comment: Why not follow the same pattern? `otherlist=400,200,730,10` and then ``stringsplit, otherlist, otherlist,`,`` and `Sleep otherlist%counter%`?